# Delete Top 10 record from table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am newbie to database
I want to delete top 10 records form table without any condition on column.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? LIMIT and ORDER BY is my tip.

Comment: Define "Top 10" if there is no "condition on column" please!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just execute this one-line command :

```
DELETE FROM table LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below query to `delete` Top ten records from `Mysql`,

```
DELETE FROM table_name limit 10;
```

It deletes top 10 records from table. You can Also modify number to change number of records.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 Delete from table_name limit 0,10;
```